# Some url for parser

Tags: parsing, kotlin

I have an url array which I want to parse, how can I get it?
What I want is to see all the url in the same recyclerView.

```
doAsync {
            val array = arrayOf("https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/1.php",
                    "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/2.php")

            array.forEach
```

val url = (it)

```
            val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                val builder = GsonBuilder()
                val mGson = builder.create()

                uiThread {

                    val items: List<ModelJor>
```

items = (Arrays.asList(*mGson.fromJson(response, Array::class.java)))

```
                    val filtro = items.filter { it.estadoPartido == "Pendiente" && it.fecha != "" }

                    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)

                    val adapter = AdapNJ(activity!!, filtro)
                    recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.message) })
            queue.add(stringRequest)
        }
```

Comment: is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See **Step by step** below.

---

You can use the following statement to get the response of each url.

```
val arr = arrayOf("https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/1.php",
        "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/2.php")

arr.forEach {
    val jsonText = URL(it).readText()

    // parse jsonText to objects
    println(jsonText)
}
```

To parse json text, you can follow the instructions [here](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/kotlins-a-great-language-for-json-fcd6ef99256b).

**Edit**

To implement network connection in android,

you need to do the task in the separate thread, not in UI Thread.

Using Kotlin anko, you can easily achieve this using `doAsync`.

Just wrap the code to be run in `doAsync` clause

and wrap the resulting code in `uiThread` clause.

```
doAsync {
    val arr = arrayOf(...)
    arr.forEach {
        ...

        val result = // parsed result
        uiThread {
            doSomethingWithResult(result)
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Step by Step

Okay I'll give you step by step instructions so you can follow along with your project.

**1. Add internet permission**

We will be using internet connection, so we have to tell that we need permission to use the internet.

1. Open *app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml*.
2. Add the following tag as a child of root `<manifest>` tag.

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

**2. Add `anko` library**

We will be using `anko` library so we can handle **async tasks** easily without boilerplates.

1. Open *Gradle Scripts/build.gradle (Module: app)*
2. Add following line inside `dependencies`.

   `implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8"`
3. Click **Sync Now**.

**3. `doAsync{}` for background tasks**

To request in background, we are using `doAsync` by `anko`.

Place `doAsync` clause in where you have to make a request.

In my case, I'll be sending request when user clicks a button.

```
btnLoad.setOnClickListener { 
    doAsync { 

    }
}
```

This will cause a compile error.

To solve this, simply **import** `doAsync`.

**4. Loop through urls and fetch response**

Now we are in background, we can make requests!

Inside `doAsync`, request and fetch the response.

```
val arr = arrayOf("https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/1.php",
                "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/2.php")

arr.forEach {
    // request and fetch response
    val jsonText = URL(it).readText()
}
```

Now we have response text in `jsonText`.

**5. Parse response**

I'll just use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` to parse `jsonText`.

But it is your choice which method you will use.

You can use Gson as you described in your question.

As we now that response is in `array`, we can do as follows:

```
// we know that result json is an array
val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonText)
for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    // get each elements
    val jsonObject = jsonArray[i] as JSONObject

    // get data of each elements
    val idLocal = jsonObject.getString("idLocal")
    val idClubLocal = jsonObject.getString("idClubLocal")
    val nomLocal = jsonObject.getString("nomLocal")
}
```

**6. Do something with parsed results**

Now that we have parsed data, only thing left is to do something with it.

I'll simply log the data to the logcat.

I defined `log()` to simplify logging codes.

```
fun log(message: String) = Log.d("MainActivity", message)
```

Now I logged the data I fetched.

```
log("[item $i]")
log("idLocal: $idLocal")
log("idClubLocal: $idClubLocal")
log("nomLocal: $nomLocal")
```

From this point, when you run this code you'll be able to see the result like this in logcat.

```
MainActivity: [item 0]
MainActivity: idLocal: 0201010551
MainActivity: idClubLocal: 0201010
MainActivity: nomLocal: AAAAA
MainActivity: [item 1]
MainActivity: idLocal: 0201045201
MainActivity: idClubLocal: 0201045
MainActivity: nomLocal: BBBBB
MainActivity: [item 0]
MainActivity: idLocal: 0201010551
MainActivity: idClubLocal: 0201010
MainActivity: nomLocal: CCCCC
MainActivity: [item 1]
MainActivity: idLocal: 0201045201
MainActivity: idClubLocal: 0201045
MainActivity: nomLocal: DDDDD
```

As you see, these are the data that your urls provide.

**7. Let something run in uiThread**

Notice that all our code is running in async.

Sometimes, we need to do something with the result in **ui thread**, such as

- Update `TextView` as request
- Add new item to `RecyclerView`

For now, I will stick on logging data instead of updating uis.

To run code in ui thread, simply wrap the code with `uiThread` clause.

You might also have to import `uiThread`.

```
uiThread {
    log("[item $i]")
    log("idLocal: $idLocal")
    log("idClubLocal: $idClubLocal")
    log("nomLocal: $nomLocal")
}
```

The code works exactly same except the logging now works in ui thread.

**FULL CODE**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnLoad.setOnClickListener {
            doAsync {
                val arr = arrayOf("https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/1.php",
                    "https://rafelcf.000webhostapp.com/rafel_cf/2.php")
                arr.forEach {
                    val jsonText = URL(it).readText()
                    // we know that result json is an array
                    val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonText)
                    for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        // get each elements
                        val jsonObject = jsonArray[i] as JSONObject
                        // get data of each elements
                        val idLocal = jsonObject.getString("idLocal")
                        val idClubLocal = jsonObject.getString("idClubLocal")
                        val nomLocal = jsonObject.getString("nomLocal")
                        uiThread {
                            log("[item $i]")
                            log("idLocal: $idLocal")
                            log("idClubLocal: $idClubLocal")
                            log("nomLocal: $nomLocal")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun log(message: String) = Log.d("MainActivity", message)
}
```

Comment: @RafelC.F You have to use another thread to do network connection. Check my edited answer.

Comment: If perfect but after almost 2 days, I do not get the recyclerView or the filter

Comment: Perfect I know I'll get the recycler and the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

```
fun getPendientes() {

        doAsync {

            for(num in 1..30) {

                val arr = arrayOf(
                        "http://www.url$num")

                arr.forEach {

                    val jsonText = URL(it).readText()

                    val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonText)
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

                        val pendientes = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i)

                        val nomLocal = pendientes.getString("nomLocal")
                        val resulLocal = pendientes.getString("resulLocal")
                        val escudoLocal = pendientes.getString("escudoLocal")
                        val nomVisitante = pendientes.getString("nomVisitante")
                        val resulVisitante = pendientes.getString("resulVisitante")
                        val escudoVisitante = pendientes.getString("escudoVisitante")
                        val fecha = pendientes.getString("fecha")
                        val hora = pendientes.getString("hora")
                        val estadoPartido = pendientes.getString("estadoPartido")
                        val abreviaturaEstado = pendientes.getString("abreviaturaEstado")

                        modelPendientes.add(ModelPendientes(nomLocal, resulLocal, escudoLocal,
                                nomVisitante, resulVisitante, escudoVisitante, fecha, hora, estadoPartido,abreviaturaEstado))

                        val filtro = modelPendientes
                                .filter {it ->
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "P" ||
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "A" ||
                                        it.abreviaturaEstado == "S" &&
                                        it.fecha != ""
                                }

                        uiThread {
                            /*val filtro = modelPendientes.filter { it.abreviaturaEstado == "A" ||
                                    it.abreviaturaEstado == "S" || it.abreviaturaEstado == "P" && it.fecha != ""*/
                            //}
                            recyclerView!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)
                            adapter = PendientesAdapter(filtro, activity!!)
                            recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```